# How to use both struts2 ssl plugin and json plugin

Tags: json, ssl, struts2

I've encountered a problem when using struts2.
I want to use both struts2 json plugin and ssl plugin. 
But in the struts.xml they need to extend default packages.

```
   <package name="myPackage1" extends="json-default">
   <package name="myPackage1" extends="ssl-default">
```

How can I use both of the plugins?
Thanks!!

Comment: combine them together like `<package name="myPackage1" extends="json-default , ssl-default">`

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a package you must declare both extensions together, instead of declaring a package two times.

Try using

```
<package name="myPackage1" extends="json-default,ssl-default">
```